# Eclipse not detecting main method javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar

I've been desperately trying to export my javafx eclipse project to a runnable jar file. However, I keep getting an error:

```
`JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
    Could not find main method from given launch configuration.
`
```

I'm pretty sure I have a main method in my Main class. I've successfully ran the program multiple times. However, I had to manually set my main class location in the run configuration for my javafx project as eclipse is not detecting my main method.

Here is my [main](https://hastebin.com/pumuyulido.java) class.
When right clicking my main class file in the project explorer and choosing run as -> Java Application, Eclipse complains that Selection does not contain a main type

Answer (score 0):

The `duplicate entry: module-info.class` lines indicate that you want to create a **single JAR** from multiple Java modules, which is **not possible using [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System)**, a JAR cannot contain multiple Java modules.

So, when using JPMS with a JAR on the Java Build Path the ***Runnable JAR file*** export wizard must be used with the option ***Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR***.

Comment: it doesn't work.
Now I'm left with this:
`JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
  Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Quizzer/src/resources/quizzes.txt'.
  Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Quizzer/src/resources/quizzes.txt'.
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
    Could not find main method from given launch configuration.
`

Comment: Refresh the project (hit F5 on the project) to fix out of sync and try again.

Comment: Still not working. I spammed f5 while opening my main class for quite a while, but when i do runas java application, I still get selection does not contain main class. I've attached my main class in the question